# Headless testing of remote JavaScript web-applications

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, headless-browser

There is an web-application, that needs to be tested. This application uses AJAX and jQuery. Tests have to be written for all possible interactions with the browser and client-side. There are some tools for this, for example, Selenium IDE, but I wonder if it is possible to use any headless browser.

So, requirements for the testing system are:

1. Query pages from the remote server, simulate browser behavior (basically we give the headless browser the URL, browser fetches the page and launches tests on it);
2. Inject tested JavaScript or test JavaScript already loaded on the remote page;
3. Use any of testing frameworks than can be integrated with any of CI software (Jasmine, Mocha etc.).

It is possible to use mocking techniques when dealing with AJAX requests, for example, but I'm trying to test real-life application. Hope that this question will be useful for anybody.

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I investigated this topic, there is no means of doing this so far.

In my case I have a server PHP application, that talks with the outside world using REST interface. My JavaScript code talks to server and performs some interface manipulations depending on responses. So, my goal is to test the JavaScript code, but it hardly relies on the server side. So, I have to ways of testing JavaScript:

1. Using **mocks**, consider looking up [this article](http://jamescryer.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/uitesting/). You basically simulate you server-side API. There is a problem with this method - whenever you change your API, you have to perform corresponding changes in your mocks, so the testing set will be actual.
2. Calling JavaScript testing utilities **directly** from PHPUnit tests (or whatever server-side testing is used) - there are no solution for this yet, unfortunately. But this method will save a lot of developers time (no need to rewrite mocks for 100-200 example queries), also we can guide the server's behavior on-the-fly.

Please, give a feedback on the second approach. If it is really needed, I guess it make sense to implement it.